# What does the 5 mean when a damage roll is 5 (1d6+2)

Tags: dnd-5e

I'm teaching myself 5e from absolute scractch, and I'm trying to roll an attack with a shortbow. AC modifiers + initiatives are fine, but calculating the actual damage is something that's tripping me up.

Does '5(1d6+2) piercing damage' mean *Roll 1d6 + 2 for a maximum of 5 damage* or something else entirely?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Some DMs prefer not to roll every attack a monster does, and instead rely on a precomputed value. It gives the game consistency and makes things move more quickly. The 5 is the suggested value for this precomputed roll, as it's (3 + 2), or (1*(6/2) + 2).

Personally, I'd suggest you roll, as most people I know find it part of the excitement.

Answer (score 2):

5 is the average number you would get, rounded down, if you rolled 1d6+2 many times. A DM, or player, if the DM agrees, could use this number instead of rolling the prescribed dice.